# No access to parent pivot attributes in relationship method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

There are 3 models: Order, Product and Price

Each *Order* has many *Products*, each *Product* has a *Price* which depends on the *Order*'s *price_group_id* field.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['quantity']);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function price() {
        return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->where('price_group_id', '=', $this->pivot->pivotParent->price_group_id);
    }
}
```

*Price* model has *id, product_id, price_group_id* and *value* fields.

I retreive *Order*'s *price_group_id* attribute in *Product* model with *$this->pivot->pivotParent* and it works fine in Laravel, but it doesn't work with Lighthouse queries: *"Trying to get property 'pivotParent' of non-object"*. It seems like there is no pivot and pivotParent at all.

Is there any way to get a parent pivot attributes or maybe some other way to implement such relationships?

A part of GraphQL schema:

```
type Query {
    orders: [Order!]! @all
    order(id: ID! @eq): Order @find
}

type Order {
    id: ID!
    price_group_id: ID!
}

type Product {
    id: ID!
    price: Price @hasOne
}

type Price {
    id: ID!
    value: Float!
    price_group_id: ID!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried some ways to solve this, including accessor instead of relationship method. pivotParent returns null, but I got an access to pivot! So I could get the price_group_id and relative price this way:

```
public function getPriceAttribute() {
    return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->where('price_group_id', Order::find($this->pivot->order_id)->price_group_id)->first()->value;
}
```

The product schema:

```
type Product {
    id: ID!
    price: Float
}
```

Comment: In my experience, it's less complicated to just have price as an attribute rather than as a separate class/model.